# ¿Cómo calculo los elementos de la diagonal inversa de una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando realizar una función que halle la diferencia entre las diagonales de una matriz en Python bastante sencilla pero no logro que realice bien la suma de los elementos de la diagonal secundaria, ya he probado de varias maneras y no me da el numero correcto. Si me pueden ayudar, 
esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
def diagonalDifference(a):

    suma_diagonalprincipal = 0
    suma_diagonalsecundaria = 0
    n=len(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        suma_diagonalprincipal = suma_diagonalprincipal + a[i][i]
        if i!=1:
        suma_diagonalsecundaria = suma_diagonalsecundaria + a[i][n-i+1]

    dif = suma_diagonalprincipal - suma_diagonalsecundaria
    return dif
```

Comment: Recuerda que en python la cantidad de espacios importa. Poner un if y luego una expresión exactamente al mismo nivel es un error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ya lo ha expuesto Saul en su respuesta. Además el `if` no es necesario, y de serlo lo que ha de ejecutarse cuando se cumpla debe ir identado un nivel más para que quede dentro del  condicional.

Recuerda que en Python el indexado empieza en 0, por lo que el **último indice de una lista es su longitud menos 1**. Imaginemos una matriz de 3 X 3, los índices que necesitas generar son:

```
[(0, 0),  ____ , (0, 2)]
[ ____ , (1, 1),  ____ ]
[(2, 0),  ____ , (2, 2)]
```

El índice de la fila ya lo generas en el `for`, el índice de la columna en el caso de la diagonal principal es siempre el mismo que el de la fila. El indice de la columna en el caso de la diagonal secundaria es siempre el índice del último elemento de la fila (`len(matriz) - 1`) menos el indice de la fila en la que estamos. En este punto conviene observar que **Python permite el indexado negativo**, con `lista[-1]` obtenemos el último elemento de la lista, por lo que `a[i][n-i-1]` es equivalente a `a[i][-i-1]`.

Bien, dicho esto  y dado que la pregunta es algo más general, podemos implementar esto de otras formas sin salir de Python ni usar ninguna biblioteca. Si solo necesitas la diferencia puedes evitar el cálculo por separado de la suma de ambas matrices, lo que simplifica el código:

```
def diagonal_difference(matriz):
    dif = 0

    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        dif += matriz[i][i] - matriz[i][-i-1]

    return dif
```

Podemos ir un paso más allá para que el código sea más eficiente usando `enumerate` para obtener la fila y su índice en vez de usar `range`:

```
def diagonal_difference(matriz):
    dif = 0

    for i, row in enumerate(matriz):
        dif += row[i] - row[-i-1]

    return dif
```

Otro paso más es usar la función preconstruida `sum` en un generador por compresión, lo que evita también la llamada a `len`:

```
def diagonal_difference(matriz):
    dif = sum((row[i] - row[-i - 1] for i, row in enumerate(matriz)))
    return dif
```

Si quieres obtener el valor absoluto de la  diferencia basta con que al retornar hagas `return abs(dif)`. La matriz a de ser cuadrada por definición, por lo que de no validar esto antes, sería oportuno realizar una validación dentro de la propia función:

```
def diagonal_difference(matriz):
    if not all(len(row)==len(matriz) for row in matriz):
        raise ValueError("The matrix must be square")
    # ...
```

> **Nota**: `dif += ...` equivale en este caso a `dif  = dif + ...`

Comment: Tome su like buen hombre, si que toma su tiempo para responder

Answer (score 3):

Parece que tu problema es unicamente un signo. Si cambias el +1 por un -1 en los corchetes de la diagonal secundaria ya lo calcula bien.

```
def diagonalDifference(a):

    suma_diagonalprincipal = 0
    suma_diagonalsecundaria = 0
    n = len(a)

    for i in range(len(a)):
        suma_diagonalprincipal = suma_diagonalprincipal + a[i][i]
        #                                      Justo aquí -> vvvvvvvvvv
        suma_diagonalsecundaria = suma_diagonalsecundaria + a[i][n-i-1]

    dif = suma_diagonalprincipal - suma_diagonalsecundaria
    return dif
```

Answer (score 0):

Me costo entender como hacerlo pero al final obtuve lo esperado.

```
n=len(matriz)
for i in range(filas):
    suma_diagonal_derecha=suma_diagonal_derecha+matriz[i][i]
    for j in range(columnas):
        if (i+j==n-1):
            suma_diagonal_izquierda=suma_diagonal_izquierda+matriz[i][j]
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho expliques tu código amigo por favor